# cannot connect to azure machine using remote desktop

Tags: windows, azure, cloud

i create a win2012r2 datacenter vm on azure. i'm trying to connect via RDC but rdc cannot connect. i use the rdp file that azure provide, and also tryied to do it by myself manually in rdc (dns:port and also ip:port) but still i can't connect. how to check where the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: Are you in a Crop. network? I means did you check the firewall settings on your side? And kindly reminder, the default RDC port is NOT 3389.

Comment: Shaun, i've tryied to change the port from 50286 to 3389, so it seams that my corp firewall block some range. thanks :)

Comment: Good to see you got the reason. Would you please accept my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in a Crop. network? I means did you check the firewall settings on your side? And kindly reminder, the default RDC port is NOT 3389.